# Difference between どうにかならない! and 仕方がない when used as an interjection

Tags: nuances, expressions

From what I've been seeing, the two have somewhat similar meanings when used as interjections.

Answer (score 2):

どうにもならない (not どうにかならない) and 仕方がない are similar like you say.

どうにもならない is however reserved for significant things as it conveys irreversibility. E.g. the following is fine:

> 電気消すの忘れた
> 仕方がないな

The following is odd because surely it's easy to go back and just switch it off.

> 電気消すの忘れた
> どうにもならないな

The following is thus natural again:

> あー、家出る時電気消すの忘れた！もう飛行機あと５分で出るのに
> どうにもならないな

Because the situation *is* irreversible.

Similarly, the following is natural:

> ごめん、名札書くときちょっと字汚くなっちゃった
> 仕方ないな

But the following is almost provocational:

> ごめん、書くときちょっと字汚くなっちゃった
> どうにもならないな

(Because "Why is this person accusing me of some irreversible mistake, when it just looks slightly bad?")